# Where does subprocess.Popen look for the argument process? (Python)

Tags: python, subprocess

For example, when I type:
child = Popen('cmd'), how does the interpreter know where to look for cmd? and if I want to use my custom process, where do I put it that it will get recognized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `env` option for `Popen`.

The default behavior is that the environment of the python process is inherited.

You can define the environment variables yourself (and add something to PATH) with the `env` option the following way.

```
import subprocess, os
my_env = os.environ.copy()
my_env["PATH"] = "/usr/sbin:/sbin:" + my_env["PATH"]
subprocess.Popen(my_command, env=my_env)
```

Answer (score 1):

It will look in the directories in the PATH environment variable.  But you can always specify an absolute or relative path, so if you know where your custom process is located, you can just give the full path to it.